# UI5 - Add Style Class in JSONView

Tags: css, json, controls, sapui5

I have a problem, how can add a new style class to a JSON-Control in OpenUI5 or SAPUI5?
I can't find examples!
I need the constructor syntax!

Here my response in JSON:

```
{
"Type": "sap.m.IconTabBar",
"id": "icontabbar_2cf94283-10ff-4b05-a912-5212a579f92e",
"items":[
    {
        "Type": "sap.m.IconTabFilter"
        "class": "tabtest"
        "content": [,…]
        "count": ""
        "icon": "sap-icon://message-information"
        "id": "icontabfilter_7e0ff4f0-9871-49da-9a4a-af048eb447a0"
        "key": "details"
        "text": "Details"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: if you are using JSON-Views then you cant add it in the view directly. You have to retreive the control byId and use `addStyleClass`

Comment: I use gerneric ids!

Comment: The constuctor syntax would be good!

Answer (score 1):

To any controls whether they are predefined ones for example: `DateTimePicker` or `TextView` or it may be custom control you can use `addStyleClass` to add styles to your controls.

Here is an example:

**Openui5 predefined control**

```
new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
  text: "Title"
}).addStyleClass("myclass"),
```

**Custom control**

```
new my.control.Custom({
  text: "Title"
}).addStyleClass("myclass"),
```

Alternatively you can assign an **id** , you can add style class using jquery.

```
//for jsview
new sap.ui.commons.TextView("textviewid",{
  text: "Title"
});
//for xmlview
<Text id="textviewid" text="My Text" />
//Adding class in jquery
$("#textviewid").addClass("myclass");
```

or simply add `class="myCustomClass"` as stated by @cschuff

Comment: I known this method, but I need the syntax for the constructor like XML Views "<Text class="myCustomClass" text="My Text" />!

Comment: isn't above the one for constructors.

Comment: I don't know the id!

Comment: No you can assign an id

Comment: or can you post your control in the question so that it would be more clear

Comment: The id is generated! The code is at the top of the page!

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition to SiddPs answer: If you use `XMLView` you can add classes like this:

```
<Text class="myCustomClass" text="My Text" />
```

Comment: It surely does. Did you check the actual DOM-Node for the class?

Comment: Yes I have check the the DOM!

Comment: Well, then I suppose you do something wrong: http://jsbin.com/rozuhicevu/1/edit?html,output